# Linear functional: continuous at $x_0=0 \iff$ continuous at all $x$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $f$ be a linear functional  on a normed space $(X, ||\cdot ||)$. Prove that $f$ is continuous $\iff$ it is continuous at all $x \in X$.

Backward direction is trivial: Since $f$ is continuous at all $x$, then it is continuous at $0$ in particular.

Forward direction: Assume $f$ is continuous at $x_0=0$, then $$\forall \varepsilon >0, \, \, \exists \delta >0: \, \, ||f(y)-f(0)||=||f(y-0)||=||f(y)||< \varepsilon \, \, \text{whenever} \, \, ||y-0||<\delta, \, \, y \in X$$ Fix $x_0 \in X$. Fix $\varepsilon _0 >0$. Then there exists $\delta_0>0$ such that $$||f(x)-f(x_0)||=||f(x-x_0)||=||f(y)||<\varepsilon_0$$ We let $y=x-x_0$ and the last "$<$" holds because we know $||f(y)||< \varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$ so in particular, it holds for $\varepsilon_0$.

Is this OK?

Comment: I believe your answer is correct!

Comment: The title says something else as the first two lines of the body.

Comment: An unnecessary step in your equalities though, since for any linear $f$, $f(0)=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I believe it looks good, but I was a bit confused at the following parts:

You assume that $f$ is continuous at $x_0 = 0$, and fix some $x_0\in X$. I would give this latter $x_0$ another name, as it is different from $x_0$.

You write "Then there exists $\delta_0>0$ such that...", but you don't mention what you need this $\delta_0$ for. Remember to mention "whenever $||y||<\delta_0$."

Answer (score 1):

Another approach slightly different: suppose $\;x_n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}x_0\;$, then

$$x_n-x_0\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0\stackrel{\text{cont.}}\implies \overbrace{f(x_n-x_0)}^{=f(x_n)-f(x_0)}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}f(0)=0$$

but the last part is the same as

$$0=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(f(x_n)-f(x_0)\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)-f(x_0)\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(x_0)$$